# Map a map response to a map in typescript/angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Working on angular4 for a while, today I came to a scenario where my service is returning me a map instead of a JSON response. How can I map that service with my map. Error I am getting in visual studio `Type Info cannot be assigned to type Map<string, Info>`. My code is as below: Please advice me did I make a correct  model class? how to map service map response to my map.

response from service

```
{
"1":{
     "id":"1",
     "name":"Anna"
    },
"2":{
     "id":"2",
     "name":"Martin"
    }
}
```

ts file

```
    myMap: Map<string, Info>;
     this.groupService.fetchInfo().subscribe(data => {
     this.myMap= data; // Error in visual studio: Type Info cannot be 
                       // assigned to type Map<string, Info>
    });
```

Info model

```
// Not sure if this model structure is correct
export interface Info{
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

service

```
fetchInfo(): Observable<Info>{
 const url = "/info/getInfo";
 return this.httpClient.get<Info>(url);
}
```

Comment: Cant you just change your service's return type from `<Info>` to `<Map>` ?

Comment: try this  myMap: Info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is still JSON, it's just that the JSON is an object that maps a string to an `Info` type. So it can defined as `{ [key: string]: Info }`. So your service either needs to defined as:

```
fetchInfo(): Observable<{ [key: string]: Info }>
```

Or if you want a real JavaScript map (not an object), the service needs to explicitly convert the object into a map. The whole thing should look something like this (I didn't have a chance to check the syntax):

```
fetchInfo(): Observable<Map<string, Info>> {
    return this.httpClient.get<{ [key: string]: Info }>(url).map(response => { 
        const map = new Map();
        Object.keys(response).forEach(key => {
            map.set(key, response[key]);
        });
        return map;
    });
}
```